# How to set final element in array equal to source vertex in Dijkstra's Algorithm?

Tags: java

I want the program to return back to the source, as per the travelling salesman problem. The program should visit all vertices and then return to the source node, counting the distance from the previous node to the source node. At the moment, if I add another City object from the main class, it calculates the shortest distance, which puts it immediately after the source node A.

My current output is [A, D, C, B] but I want to get [A,D,C,B,A]. It needs to return to the source node and track the distance in that way. At the moment, it does not track it. Right now the total distance is 23, but I am expecting 28.

Here is my NearestNeighbour class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class NearestNeighbour {
    public Route findShortestRoute(ArrayList<City> cities) {
        ArrayList<City> shortestRouteCities = new ArrayList<City>(cities.size());
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Initial Route           ==> " + Arrays.toString(cities.toArray()));
        System.out.println("w/ total distance: " + new Route(cities).calculateTotalDistance());
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        City city = cities.get(0);
        updateRoutes(shortestRouteCities, cities, city);
        while (cities.size() >= 1) {
            city = getNextCity(cities, city);
            updateRoutes(shortestRouteCities, cities, city);
        }
        return new Route(shortestRouteCities);
    }
    private void updateRoutes(ArrayList<City> shortestRouteCities, ArrayList<City> cities, City city) {
        shortestRouteCities.add(city);
        cities.remove(city);
        System.out.println("Cities In Shortest Route ==> " + Arrays.toString(shortestRouteCities.toArray()));
        System.out.println("Remaining Cities         ==> " + Arrays.toString(cities.toArray()) + "\n");
    }
    private City getNextCity(ArrayList<City> cities, City city) {
        return cities.stream().min((city1, city2) -> {
            int flag = 0;
            if (city1.measureDistance(city) < city2.measureDistance(city)) flag = -1;
            else if (city1.measureDistance(city) > city2.measureDistance(city)) flag = 1;
            return flag;
        }).get();
    }
}
```

Here is my Driver class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Driver {
    private ArrayList<City> initialCities = new ArrayList<City>(Arrays.asList(
            new City("A", 1.0, 1.0),
            new City("B", 2.0, 9.0),
            new City("C", 6.0, 6.0),
            new City("D", 7.0, 2.0)
  
            //new City("Denver", 39.7392, -104.9903),
            //new City("Los Angeles", 34.0522, -118.2437),
            //new City("Chicago", 41.8781, -87.6298),
            //new City("New York", 40.7128, -74.0059),
            //new City("Dallas", 32.7767, -96.7970),
            //new City("Seattle", 47.6062, -122.3321)
        //new City("Sydney", -33.8675, 151.2070),
        //new City("Tokyo", 35.6895, 139.6917(,
        //new City("Cape Town", -33.9249, 18.4241)
    ));
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Driver driver = new Driver();
        ArrayList<City> cities = new ArrayList<City>();
        cities.addAll(driver.initialCities);
        driver.printShortestRoute(new NearestNeighbour().findShortestRoute(cities));
        
    }
    
    private void printShortestRoute(Route shortestRoute){
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Shortest route found so far: " + shortestRoute);
        System.out.println("w/ total distance: " + shortestRoute.calculateTotalDistance());
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output and what do you get?

Comment: My current output is [A, D, C, B] but I want to get [A,D,C,B,A]. It needs to return to the source node and track the distance in that way. At the moment, it does not track it. Right now the total distance is 23, but I am expecting 28.

Comment: What’s stopping you from appending the first element to the end of the path?

Comment: If I add element A to the path again, it calculates the shortest distance using this element. However, the calculation occurs at the wrong time, as it orders the elements by shortest distance. This is the output I get:                                                                                              "Shortest route found so far: [A, A, D, C, B]
w/ total distance: 23 "                                                                                                                 But I want it to return "[A, D, C, B , A]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're removing each city after the visit. So, the source node was gone from your city list soon after you've finished working with it.

So, according to you, if you need to revisit the source, you can keep a destinationNode city and assign the source city to this. In `FindShortestRoute` method:

```
City city = cities.get(0);
City destinationNode = cities.get(0);
updateRoutes(shortestRouteCities, cities, city);
while (cities.size() >= 1) {
    city = getNextCity(cities, city);
    updateRoutes(shortestRouteCities, cities, city);
    if(cities.size == 0) {
        shortestRouteCities.add(destinationNode);
    }
}
```